# detecting stack overwrite error

Tags: c, debugging, arm, cortex-m

I'm developing a software for the Cortex-M3 embedded micro controller (Atmel SAM3S)
I using the IAR EWARM IDE & compiler.
I suspect that for some reason I have a buffer overflow, or a memory leak, which causes the stack to be corrupted, because I suddenly find myself stuck outside of my code space.

The reason I ask this question, is that it's really hard finding out what actually caused this mess-up, and I want to know which techniques are you using when you want to find out the cause of the issue.

Are you using memory debuggers, in-circuit trace debugging hardware, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using canary values. This is how it basically goes - say you have some `struct`:

```
struct foo {
    unsigned long bar;
    void * baz;
};
```

Modify it so it looks like this:

```
struct foo {
    unsigned long canary1;
    unsigned long bar;
    void * baz;
    unsigned long canary2;
};
```

When you initialize the `struct`, put some arbitrary values into `canary1` and `canary2`. Whenever you do some operation on your `struct`, check if the values stay the same. This way, if you have a buffer overflow or stack smashing, you'll detect it. You can do the same inside functions with automatic variables:

```
int foo(int bar) {
      unsigned long canary1 = 0xDEADBABE;
      char baz[20];
      unsigned long canary2 = 0xBAD0C0DE;
      ...
}
```

And so on. Don't forget to check that the values remain the same before you `return`. Also, if you can get your code to consistently jump to the same location, try putting some code there (or a breakpoint) and get a stack trace.

GCC knows how to add these canary values by itself, but I don't know if your compiler can do that. But you could still do it manually.

Comment: We do something similar where we will place a "master" canary value at the end of our data and bss (our stack grows backwards from the end). We initialize the value on startup, and constantly check it in case of stack overflows or random writes.

Answer (score 2):

The program counter is a register, and as such it cannot be "overwritten". What might happen is, as you say, that the stack gets overwritten and then you execute a return instruction which reads an invalid return address from the stack, thus causing a jump into la-la-land.

My favourite debugging method is printing things out, which might be difficult on an embedded target, of course. The second-best would be to step through the suspect routine.

You should also investigate things that are known to cause jumps, such as interrupt service routines.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue using IAR EWARM on an STM32. Memory dumps, disassembly, canaries, all turned up nothing. Finally rolled back to an earlier version of EWARM and the problem went away. I sent a message to IAR support but never heard back. I'm sorry I don't remember which version of EWARM this was. It was a few projects ago.

I would keep a memory window open and try the canary test first. If it still randomly jumps out of code space, try installing an older version of EWARM.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can add is that with ARM chips, it is possible that there was a BL somewhere instead of a BX or BLX causing the chip to go into the wrong Thumb/ARM mode.  Not as common with later chips, but still...

When I find jumps to nowhere, I look for bad function pointer tables, overwrites of any interrupt vector tables, and yes, stack overflow which is the easiest to test.  Drop known bytes values into your stack area and when the crash occurs, see how much stack you had remaining with a debugger.  If none, there you go.

I'd also do the standard see what's changed in the last X days stuff to try and isolate any problems.  Finally, just printf the heck out of your code to try and narrow where the bad jump is occurring.  If you can get it down to a function or two, you can trace the assembler and see if it's a compiler issue, a memory issue, or an interrupt issue pretty quickly.  Good luck!